# Libsourcey missing -fPIC compilation error

Tags: shared-libraries, webrtc, fpic, libsourcey

I'am trying to run the LibSourcey to use the Webrtc Streaming Server.

The thing is that i can't seem to make it work.
I struggled to cmake the project on my Ubuntu 16.04(Regexp in cmake files) but now its fixed . 
The problem that i actually got is a shared object bug at compiling time :

```
usr/bin/ld: /home/kimmie/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswresample.a(options.o): 
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; 
recompile with -fPIC

/home/kimmie/ffmpeg_build/lib/libswresample.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

av/CMakeFiles/av.dir/build.make:783: recipe for target 'av/libscy_av.so.1.0.2' failed
```

Any help would be very much appreciated as i don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit this same error on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

I ended up recompiling FFmpeg with flags to build the shared libraries. Following the code example boxes in the [FFmpeg Compilation Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu), I added the following two flags to the ./configure lines where applicable:

- --enable-pic
- --enable-shared

I removed the `--disable-shared` flags as well.

I added `--enable-pic` and `--enable-shared` to every component and removed the flag if it returned a message that it was unrecognized for that component. At least libx264, libfdk-acc, and libmp3lame needed --enable-shared. And then for the final FFmpeg (copy and pasted from FFmpeg guide linked to above):

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
 --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
 --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
 --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
 --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
 --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
 --enable-gpl \
 --enable-libass \
 --enable-libfdk-aac \
 --enable-libfreetype \
 --enable-libmp3lame \
 --enable-libopus \
 --enable-libtheora \
 --enable-libvorbis \
 --enable-libvpx \
 --enable-libx264 \
 --enable-libx265 \
 --enable-nonfree \
 --enable-pic \
 --enable-shared
```

> Note the last two lines in my example are different than the FFmpeg
>   guide.

After you do all of that, it's probably best to delete the Libsourcey source and build folder and start over with that.

It took me about 4-5 days off and on to finally compile and successfully build Libsourcey with FFmpeg and WebRTC dependencies. I hit some other snags as well, so be sure to tag me if you have other questions. Note: I am noob at Linux building and not solid on all of the concepts; this is just what worked for me and perhaps it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linkage error, not a compilation error. You haven't run into a bug,
you have just attempted a linkage that cannot work.

You are trying to build a shared library `libscy_av.so`. All the object
files that are linked in a shared library must consist of [Position Independent
Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). To generate
such an object file with gcc, you compile with the option `-fPIC`.

The linker discovers that your shared libary requires the object file
`options.o`, which is a member of the static library `libswresample.a`. It then
discovers that this `options.o` is not PIC, and so cannot be linked in
a shared library. The linkage fails and the linker advises you that
`options.o` must be recompiled with the `-fPIC` compiler option.

To comply with that advice, you would have to rebuild the static library `libswresample.a` from source, with `-fPIC` added to the compiler flags.

You might do that, but it is unusual for object files in a static library to
be PIC, and there is an easier option. Your mistake was in linking against
the static version of `libswresample` (`libswresample.a`) rather than the
shared version (`libswresample.so`), which will be PIC. Just correct that mistake. If you install
`libswresample.a` from a dev package provided by your package manager, then
it will also provide `libswresample.so`. If you have built `libswresample`
from source, then the build system will also build both.